# nodejs : how to log to screen AND to file?

Tags: linux, node.js

- I use console.log in my node.js: that way I can log to screen
  ex:

  node myscript.js

If I use 
`node myscript.js>log.txt` then I log to file log.txt

**How can I log to screen AND to file ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `tee`.

```
node myscript.js | tee log.txt
```

Comment: there are unwanted characters like ESC and some numbers is there a command to remove them as well?

Answer (score 6):

If you want this behavior to be persistent within your app, you could create a through stream and pipe it to both a writeStream and stdout.

```
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');

// Use the 'a' flag to append to the file instead of overwrite it.
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/log', {flags: 'a'});
var through = require('through2');

// Create through stream.
var t = new through();

// Pipe its data to both stdout and our file write stream.
t.pipe(process.stdout);
t.pipe(ws);

// Monkey patch the console.log function to write to our through
// stream instead of stdout like default.
console.log = function () {
  t.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

Now this will write to both stdout (terminal display) and to your log file.

[image]

You can also omit the `through` stream and just write to both streams in the monkey patched function.

```
console.log = function () {
  var text = util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n';
  ws.write(text);
  process.stdout.write(text);
};
```

The through stream just gives you a single stream you could utilize in other ways around your app and you'd always know that it was piped to both output streams. But if all you want is to monkey patch `console.log` then the latter example is sufficient :)

If you only want to do this for a single run of your app from the terminal, see [@andars' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578414/nodejs-how-to-log-to-screen-and-to-file/30578571#30578571) and the `tee` command :)

PS - [This](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L56-L58) is all that `console.log` actually does in node, in case you were wondering.

```
Console.prototype.log = function() {
  this._stdout.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

Comment: If we are using a library to log instead of console.log(), will the logs get saved into the file ?